# Rails query confusion with source, source_tag, and polymorhpism

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this query in my controller:

```
@current_checkout_location.current_submissions.pluck(:id)
```

What is this looking for and what do I have to create off of the `current_checkout_location` to make `current_submissions` appear?

This is the association off the `checkout_location` model:

```
has_many :current_submissions, through: :tours
```

and this is the tour model:

```
  has_many :current_catalog_items, class_name: 'CatalogItem', foreign_key: :current_tour_id
 has_many :current_submissions, through: :current_catalog_items, source: :catalogable, source_type: 'Submission'
```

What is going on? Are we delegating `current_submissions` to `CatalogItem` model essentially? Should I expect the `CatalogItem` model to have a `catalogable` method (due to the `source` on the `has_many :current_submissions` line?)

Basically I'm trying to create some fake data for the `@current_checkout_location` but I'm a bit confused as to what to create)

This does not work:

```
CheckoutLocation.last.current_submissions << [Submission.find(8), Submission.find(7)]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `checkout_locations`.* FROM `checkout_locations`   ORDER BY `checkout_locations`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Submission Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `submissions`.* FROM `submissions`  WHERE (purchase_status = "Complete" or purchase_status = "Purchased") AND `submissions`.`id` = 8 LIMIT 1
  Submission Load (4.5ms)  SELECT  `submissions`.* FROM `submissions`  WHERE (purchase_status = "Complete" or purchase_status = "Purchased") AND `submissions`.`id` = 7 LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughNestedAssociationsAreReadonly: Cannot modify association 'CheckoutLocation#current_submissions' because it goes through more than one other association.
```

Answer (score 0):

> ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughNestedAssociationsAreReadonly: Cannot
>   modify association 'CheckoutLocation#current_submissions' because it
>   goes through more than one other association.

You have `has_many :current_submissions, through: :tours in checkout_location` and also you have  `has_many :current_submissions, through: :current_catalog_items, source: :catalogable, source_type: 'Submission'` in `Tour` model which creates a **Circular reference in relationships (source reflection)** problem. Remove the `has_many :current_submissions, through: :tours` from `current_location`. This should fix your problem.

```
#current_location.rb
has_many :tours
```